# Logout from all devices in java spring

Tags: java, spring, logout

I have created a cutom SSO for my web-application using a token to be saved in database. Now I am storing all the tokens as a json for a user, and store that as a cookie. Now I want to implement logout from all devices feature .

How can I approach it? How can I get the particular sessions that are stored in server except the current session ?

Comment: Are you validating the tokens in the cookie for every request, or only once when the session is created? If you do it for every request, deleting all tokens for a user will do the trick. If you only evaluate the token when the sessions is created, then you need to know which sessions belong to what user, which should be possible if you add a `HttpSessionListener`to get a callback when sessions are created.

Comment: okay. Thanks @KlausGroenbaek. 

I am creating the token once the user is signed in and store the token in a cookie. No if I delete a cookie from table, and that particular user is signed in at that time. How can the user get logged out ?

I am new to web-application, so can you please give me a link or show me a sample code how can I achieve it in a good way ?